# How to retrieve username and password from dnn database. Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to find out if the username and password exist for a user when logging in; however with the password encrypted and I'm not decrypting the password. How can I select the user that's logging from the database and allow them to log in to the system or error if there's not a match. I'm using asp.net. I keep getting this error message: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. Think it would have something to do with the connection string.

I'm just trying search/select the database and then allow the user to login, the user is not entering the encrypted password but rather plain text so how do I work with that

Login.aspx.cs

```
 protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string username = txtUserName.Text.ToString();
    string password = txtPassword.Text;
    MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username);
    mu.ChangePassword(mu.ResetPassword(), password);


}
```

Comment: So you are trying to validate a username/password combo to allow them to login? (by validating a username/password combo). See the problem here...

Comment: @VDWWD; you didn't show the problem; is there's another way to achieve this

Comment: If you want to log in to a DNN website, you have to use the `UserController`: http://www.dotnetnukeru.com/dnndocs/api/html/T_DotNetNuke_Entities_Users_UserController.htm

Comment: I'm not trying to login to a dnn website; i'm login into a different system using username and password from the dnn database

Comment: @VDWWD; is possible to assist